# Pass function name to other function and call from a different file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a file with a simple class and a method:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
  public function test()
  {
    doThis($this->bar());
  }

  public function bar()
  {
    echo 'foo';
  }
}
```

and another 'helper' file which is autoloader and therefore it's available in the whole application:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('doThis'))
{
    function doThis($function)
    {
        echo 'this must run';
        call_user_func($function);
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting is to print `this must run` and then 'foo' to the screen.

However, I only see `foo`. I suppose it's because this is not how to call methods from other classes.

My question is: how can I call both the `bar` method from the `test` method while having `doThis` as the wrapper in another file?

I'm using PHP8.

Comment: How do you call `$foo->test()` or `$foo->bar`? Also your `bar` should return callable `return [$this, 'zar'];` to be used inside `call_user_func()`

Comment: You actually invoke the method first `$this->bar()`, this will get evaluated before a call to `doThis` is made, passing it no value since `$this->bar()` returns no value. (in short, you don't 'pass a function (callable) to doThis')

Comment: @Justinas I call $foo->test() in the same class under a different method like this: `$this->test();`

Comment: @Radical_Activity alter `test` to `doThis(fn () => $this->bar());` and it would work since you then pass it a callable to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a function as a parameter you're passing the result of this function:

```
doThis($this->bar());
```

$this->bar() actually executes the function, and passes the response "foo" to the function doThis. So instead of a valid callback, the doThis function receives a string.

doThis also cannot access the function this way, there are 2 things you can do to make this work:

- Wrap the "$this->bar();" in a anonymous function:

  doThis(function() {
  $this->bar();
  });
- Pass the function in the following format:

  doThis([$this, 'bar']);

Both solutions work, I personally prefer the first one.

More info here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php